# Use Union-Find to get the equivalence classes

Tags: ocaml

I have a simple code of union-find as below:

```
let rec find p x =
      if p.(x) = x
      then x
      else
        let y = find p (p.(x)) in
        p.(x) <- y;
        y;;       
let union x y p =
  p.(find p y) <- p.(find p x);
  p
```

Example:

```
let a = [|0;1;2;3;4|]

let print_array a =
 Array.iter (fun i -> Printf.printf "%i" i; print_string " ") a

let print_union =
  let a = union 0 1 a in
  print_string "Result union (0, 1): ";
  print_array a;
  print_string "\n"
```

the result will be:

```
Result union (0, 1): 0 0 2 3 4
```

I am having a hard time to go further to get the disjoint-set.
For instance the example above I want to get: `{0,1},{2},{3},{4}`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'd say you could do that by going through your array filling up a `int list array` and then print only the empty lists. The timing could probably be improved though.

Comment: could you help me to have a code example? I still not clearly understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For obvious reasons, you can't print that result without going through the whole structure.

So, you want to collect inhabitants from all of your union-find:

```
let print_classes a =
 (* Let's first create an array for storing the classes *)
 let classes = Array.make (Array.length a) [] in

 (* Let's now populate it!
    I'm going backwards in the array to have nicer printing *)
 for i = (Array.length classes) - 1 downto 0
 do classes.(a.(i)) <- i :: (classes.(a.(i))) done;

 (* And now the printing *)
 Array.iter (function
   | [] -> ()
   | h::t -> Printf.printf "{%d%a}" h
             (fun c -> List.iter (fun x -> Printf.fprintf c ",%i" x)) t
   )
   classes
```

I used Printf functions for the sake of brevity, you can find their doc [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printf.html).

Note that this could probably be improved as it creates a potentially big array that may be "almost not" populated. depending on the frequency in which you'll use this function, you may want to store the equivalence class along with the class leader (I had to do that once, I used `Set` and `Map` from the stdlib).

Comment: I got an error : This expression has type int -> unit
       but an expression was expected of type unit at 
(fun c x -> Printf.fprintf c ",%i" x)

Comment: Sorry, got too fast. Fixed it (and this time, tested it).

Comment: I have an example, this is an array after doing the union (0 2):  [|2;1;2|]. The code above print out: {1;2}{0}. But from the union array, the set should be: {0;2}{1}

Comment: For me on `[|2;1;2|]` the code prints out `{1}{0,2}`. Are you sure you did the union well?

Comment: I tested again, it is correct now. Thank you very much for your help. It helps me a lots.